# Restart a Python script if killed

Tags: python, cmd, restart

I write this post because I have not found solutions for my specific case. I refer to this article, which, however, did not work for me on Windows 10 version 1909.

I programmed a "python_code_a.py" script that has the task of uploading, one at a time, all the images contained in a local folder on a converter server and to download them, always one at a time, from the server to my PC in another folder. How the script works depends on the server, which is public and not owned by me, so it is possible, approximately every two and a half hours, that the script crashes due to an unexpected connection error. Obviously, it is not possible to consider the fact that he stays all day observing the Python shell and acting in case the script stops.
As reported in the article above, I compiled a second file with the name "python_code_b.py", which had the task of acting in case "python_code_a.py" had stopped by restarting the latter. When I try to get it to run from the "python.exe" CMD, however, the latter responds to the input with "...", nothing else.

I attach a general example of "python_code_a.py":

```
processnumber= 0

photosindex= 100000

photo = 0
path = 0

while photosindex<"number of photos in folder":
  photo = str('your_path'+str(photoindex)+'.png')
  path = str('your_path'+str(photoindex)+'.jpg')

  print ('It\'s converting: '+ photo)

  import requests
  r = requests.post(
      "converter_site",
      files={
          'image': open(photo , 'rb'),
      },
      headers={'api-key': 'your_api_key'}
  )

  file= r.json()


  json_output = file['output_url']


  import urllib.request

  while photosindex<'number of photos in folder':
      urllib.request.urlretrieve( json_output , path )
      print('Finished process number: '+str(processnumber))
      break

  photosindex= photosindex +1
  processnumber= processnumber +1

  print(
  )

print('---------------------------------------------------')
print('Every pending job has been completed.')
print(
)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why not handle the error (using `try/except`) to avoid having your script crash?

Comment: I'm new in the world of Python coding, so could you tell me how I can manage try/except to handle the error? Many thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend :) the info there will be better than a comment here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use error capturing:

```
  while photosindex<"number of photos in folder":
    try:
      @Your code
    except:
      print("Something else went wrong")
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: I've run the code with your corrections but, when I simulate the connection error, nothing happens: the code stops and, even when the connection is re-established, nothing change.

Comment: In this case I've used Python Shell to execute the script, not the CMD.

Comment: Did it print "Something else went wrong", it might just failed in all images and exited

Comment: After some tries, I've adjusted the code using "try/except" adding to "except", leaving "print", the "continue" command.
This will correctly continue restart the code as long as the connection with the server will be re-established. Thanks again for your suggestion!